# Create a document-libary with SharePoint rest api

Tags: document-library, rest

Is it possible to create a document-library via SharePoint Rest API?

Answer (score 4):

I assume you mean SharePoint 2013. In this case, of course, you can create lists, including document libraries via REST, as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292552.aspx#WorkLists). For the document library you should use 101 as the [BaseTemplate](http://joelblogs.co.uk/2011/06/16/sharepoint-2010-base-types-list-template-and-definition-ids-and-content-types-ids/).

```
url: http://site url/_api/web/lists
method: POST
body: { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.List' }, 'AllowContentTypes': true, 'BaseTemplate': 101,
 'ContentTypesEnabled': true, 'Description': 'My doc. lib. description', 'Title': 'Test' }
Headers: 
    Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
    X-RequestDigest: form digest value
    accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    content-type: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    content-length:length of post body
```

If you need to access this endpoint from a Java-based application, you can use a library, like [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/) that supports this kind of HTTP-based communication. You find several samples [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-get-document-sharepoint-library.html).

As far as I the [official documentation](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.4.x/index.html) of this API, and other samples on the web (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027066/how-to-send-a-json-object-over-request-with-android) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389842/how-to-send-a-json-object-over-httpclient-request-with-android)) understand, the body of the request can be set in this case as a `StringEntity` [instance](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/StringEntity.html) via the `setEntity` [method](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase.html#setEntity(org.apache.http.HttpEntity)) of the `HttpPost` object:

```
String jsonString = "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.List' }, 'AllowContentTypes': true, 'BaseTemplate': 101,
 'ContentTypesEnabled': true, 'Description': 'My Documents Library', 'Title': 'Documents' }";
HttpEntity e = new StringEntity(jsonString);
httpPost.setEntity(e);
```

Comment: How can i do it in Java?

Comment: Do you mean JavaScript (like from the context of a SharePoint app) or really Java (for example from a context of a console application on Unix or some kind server side code)?

Comment: I mean a real Java example

Comment: @pholpar, your example is incomplete, endpoint url is missing

Comment: The first (and probably the greatest) challange / problem you might have in this case is the authentication. Do you use Windows integrated authentication in SharePoint? In which context does your Java code run? On Windows / Unix, client (I mean user) or server context? If it is Unix, or other non-Windows system, and you have Windows-integrated authentication in SharePoint, do you have an API in Java that supports that kind of authentication?

Comment: im am using Windows integrated authentication and only windows users will be able to run the code

Comment: @VadimGremyachev, thanks, it was a copy-paste error. Next time feel free to complete my code if you find such mistakes.

Comment: I am using  Apache HttpComponents and i can do post and get requests but how do i set the body for the post in Java ?

Comment: i get a 500 error when i execute the method

Answer (score 2):

How to create a Document library using SharePoint REST:

```
url: http://site url/_api/web/lists
method: POST
body: { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.List' }, 'AllowContentTypes': true, 'BaseTemplate': 101,
 'ContentTypesEnabled': true, 'Description': 'My Documents Library', 'Title': 'Documents' }
Headers: 
    Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
    X-RequestDigest: form digest value
    accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    content-type: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    content-length:length of post body
```

**References**

[Working with lists and list items with REST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292552.aspx)