# http post with body content in Java

Tags: document-library, rest

i have trying to create a document libary by using SharePoint rest api 
but how do i add the body content with the post in Java?

```
body: { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.List' }, 'AllowContentTypes': true, 'BaseTemplate': 101,
 'ContentTypesEnabled': true, 'Description': 'My Documents Library', 'Title': 'Documents' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, see my answer in [this thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/137560/create-a-document-libary-with-sharepoint-rest-api/137565).

As far as I the [official documentation](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.4.x/index.html) of this API, and other samples on the web (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027066/how-to-send-a-json-object-over-request-with-android) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389842/how-to-send-a-json-object-over-httpclient-request-with-android)) understand, the body of the request can be set in this case as a `StringEntity` [instance](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/StringEntity.html) via the `setEntity` [method](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase.html#setEntity(org.apache.http.HttpEntity)) of the `HttpPost` object:

```
String jsonString = "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.List' }, 'AllowContentTypes': true, 'BaseTemplate': 101,
 'ContentTypesEnabled': true, 'Description': 'My Documents Library', 'Title': 'Documents' }";
HttpEntity e = new StringEntity(jsonString);
httpPost.setEntity(e);
```

Comment: When i execute the method i get a http 500

Comment: Use Fiddler to see the exact request sent to the server and the response received. See the ULS logs and Windows Event Logs (Application) for the error details of the Internal Server Error (HTTP Status 500).

Comment: i use fiddler and i get a 200 ok but a 500  response from the server